# install oracle apex on oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, installation, oracle-apex

I,m installing Oracle Apex on Oracle database 11g I did the following steps:

1. Created tablespace:

   ```
   CREATE TABLESPACE apex DATAFILE 'D:\oracle\app\ali\oradata\orcl2\APEX5.DBF' SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M;
   ```
2. `sqlplus sys as sysdba`.
3. `@apexins.sql APEX APEX TEMP /i/;`

Then stared installing but it stopped with the following error :

```
...Internal messages
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04063: package body "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_LANG" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_LANG"
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_API", line 2149
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_API", line 26722
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Any help is appriciated ..thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Which versions (both Apex and Oracle database) do you use, exactly?

APEX_050100 suggests that it is Apex 5.1. If that's so, note that minimum Oracle database version you can use with it is 11.2.0.4.

Therefore, you might need to upgrade database version or - if you can't do it - install lower Apex version (note #2 that Apex 5.0.x requires at least 11.1.0.7).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that Apex 5 must be installed in ASSM tablespace. You need to uninstall Apex, and create a new APEX5 tablespace with ASSM. See this page for more help: [Apex-Help-Article](https://damir-vadas.blogspot.com/2015/08/).

Answer (score 0):

The gentleman is right.

[Apex 5.1 DB Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/requirement-Oracle-db.htm#HTMIG377)

Above Apex version 20.2.0.00.20, you must user 12c or higher.

I suffered from it some time ago

Answer (score 0):

Issue due to using non-certified version of database.
Attempting to install APEX 5.1 on a 11.1.0.7 Oracle Database which is not compatible/certified with this version of APEX.

Beginning with Application Express 5.1, the minimum database version requirement is 11.2.0.4.
For more information regarding the minimum requirements for APEX 5.1, review the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/Oracle-AE-installation-requirements.htm#HTMIG376

2.1 Oracle Database Requirements

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Oracle Application Express release 5.1 requires an Oracle Database release 11.2.0.4 or later, including Enterprise Edition and Express Edition (Oracle Database XE)

### Soluation for this problem

Install 5.0.x APEX which is certified with minimum 11.1.0.7 version of Database (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/apex-5-archive-2606313.html)
OR
Upgrade your Database to version 11.2.0.4 or later and then install the latest version of APEX (5.1.x)